# Python Json formatiing

Tags: python, json, parsing

This is my json output.How can I pull only name and Status from the below json.
breaking my head over this for last couple of days.

I need to use for loop to get this ?

```
{
    "recipes": {
        "47635": {
            "name": "Desitnation Search",
            "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
            "kitchen": "eu",
            "active": "YES",
            "created_at": 1501672231,
            "interval": 5,
            "use_legacy_notifications": false
        },
        "65568": {
            "name": "Validation",
            "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
            "kitchen": "us-west",
            "active": "YES",
            "created_at": 1522583593,
            "interval": 5,
            "use_legacy_notifications": false
        },
        "47437": {
            "name": "Gateday",
            "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
            "kitchen": "us-west",
            "active": "YES",
            "created_at": 1501411588,
            "interval": 10,
            "use_legacy_notifications": false
        }
    },
    "counts": {
        "total": 3,
        "limited": 3,
        "filtered": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear where you're stuck, as you haven't provided a [mcve] of your code so far. Yes, I'd suggest a `for` loop.

Comment: I just started to learn python. I am writing a python program to alert if the status in any one of the "status" in the above code != successful. So for this I need to know how do I extract name and status from this ..

Comment: That's interesting context, but not at all relevant to the question. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Have you done any research? What have you learned, and what do you still not know? SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service, it is here to answer specific, well-scoped questions whose answers might be useful to many people, not just the OP.

Comment: Okay.. I have passed the value to this function and tried using nested for loop. But all it returns is just 47635 and  47437

def pingdom_data(pingdom_response):
    data = []
    for check in pingdom_response.json()['recipes']:
        print check  < - This is wh
        for temp in check:
             data.append({
            'name': temp['name'],
            'status': temp['status']
           # 'resptime': check['lastresponsetime']
        })
    #print data

Comment: [Edit] the question, explain precisely what the problem is per the material in [ask].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yup use a for loop here.

```
extracted_recipes = []
for recipe in d['recipes']:
    extracted_recipes.append(recipe['name'],recipe['status'])
```

This will give you a list of tuples.

```
print(extracted_recipes)
[('Desitnation Search',"SUCCESSFUL"),("Validation","SUCCESSFUL"),("Gateday","SUCCESSFUL")]
```

Comment: getting this error.. any ideas ?

import json
import re
import requests
import subprocess
res = requests.get('https://api.tempura1.com/api/1.0/recipes', auth=('12345','123'), headers={'App-Key': 'bc9y1dmq8xsm3tykuasdd4o7ptz7'})
data = res.text
extracted_recipes = []
for recipe in data['recipes']:
  extracted_recipes.append({
            'name': recipe['name'],
            'status': recipe['status']
        })
  print extracted_recipes

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers